# Adding URL attribute to cloned jquery div row

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div id="menu"> 
    <ul  data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="a">
    <li data-role='list-divider'>DAILY NEWS</li>
    <li id="entryTemplate" class="entry" style="display:none">
        <a href="#url" rel="external"></a>
        <span class="label">Label</span>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>  




    for (var i=0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
        var row = result.rows.item(i);

        var newEntryRow = $('#entryTemplate').clone();
        newEntryRow.removeAttr('id');
        newEntryRow.removeAttr('style');
        newEntryRow.data('entryId', row.content_id);
        newEntryRow.appendTo('#menu ul');
        newEntryRow.find('.label').text(row.content_title);

        newEntryRow.find('#url').text('http://www.yahoo.com?id=row.content.id');
    }
```

I have a for statement that clones a DIV above for a piece of my jquerymobile script. I've got everything else working, but I can not figure out how to add the url attribute. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

To set the `href` to what you're after, you need to replace:

```
newEntryRow.find('#url').text('http://www.yahoo.com?id=row.content.id');
```

with a [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) call, like this:

```
newEntryRow.find('a').attr('href', 'http://www.yahoo.com?id=' + row.content.id);
```